# Post method using PHP on Azure

Tags: php, angularjs, http, azure, post

I copied and pasted this code directly from somewhere else that worked perfectly I just uploaded to my own server on azure and I get no response but there's definitely a request going in. I have no idea how it's not responding when it's the exact same code! Any ideas?

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}


$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($postdata)) {
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $username = $request->username;

    if ($username != "") {
        echo "Server returns: " . $username;
    }
    else {
        echo "Empty username parameter!";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Not called properly with username parameter!";
}
?>
```

Comment: please paste HTTP request and response (if any) logs - thanks - and HTTP codes

Answer (score 0):

As by default, when you create an Azure Web App service in PHP, there is not variable named `HTTP_ORIGIN` in PHP runtime, and the variable `REQUEST_METHOD` is only set as '`GET`. You can write code `phpinfo();` in your PHP script on Azure to check the configurations in PHP runtime on Azure.

So the code in the first 2 **`IF`** closures will not ever run. So if your AngularJs client is not in the same domain with your PHP server (they should be in one Azure Web App Service here), when your client request the PHP server, it will raise a CORS issue.

So you can set your custom `HTTP_ORIGIN` in app settings on Azure portal, which will be set in PHP runtime the your application start.

- Login [Azure classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com), header to the page to manage your website.
- Click the **CONFIGURE** tab, scroll down to the **app settings** section
- Set the **`HTTP_ORIGIN`** for your AngularJs client endpoint. E.G. If your AngularJs client runs on local, you should set the `HTTP_ORIGIN` as `localhost`:
  [image]
- Click save button at bottom nav and click restart button to restart the website to load your custom settings.

Then you can test your AngularJs application on your local server:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://<your_web_site_na,e>.azurewebsites.net/<post_page>.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: { username: 'username', password: 'password' },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
  });
```