# In PHP Linux Azure Web App, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is always set to GET, even when POST, PATCH, DELETE etc requests are made through Postman

Tags: php, azure, http, azure-web-app-service

I have a PHP app hosted on a Linux Azure App Service, which has a RESTful API component.

Inside the code for the endpoints, I have the following code for determining what type of request was made:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ) {  ...
}
else if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) { ...
}
else if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PATCH' ) { ...
}
else if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE' ) { ...
else { ...
}
```

When the PHP app is hosted locally and the API is tested with Postman, this works fine. However, when the app is hosted on Azure, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable always returns `'GET'`, no matter what the actual request method is set to in Postman.

I have done some looking into it, and found a Stack Overflow answer that said that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable is always set to `'GET'` by default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984252/14461562.

However I have been unable to find any more information on how to get the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable to work properly.

Does anyone have experience with this issue or know how to go about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have redirect rules or use wrong rules.

Add `.htaccess` file [with below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565563/post-becomes-get-after-htaccess-directives), maybe useful to you.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried removing all of the `.htaccess` rules, but the problem still occurs, so I don't think it is a `.htaccess` issue.

Comment: @DanielM I mean you should add the appropriate code in the `.htaccess` file instead of deleting it. Please refer to the example link below carefully.

Comment: The answer in the link said to not redirect POST requests using `.htaccess` rules. So I tried removing all of the `.htaccess` rules, yet the problem still occurred. I tried using the code snippet but it also did not work.